# Error count up and down when catch event mouse wheel in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a sample .vue file, when run it happen error `this.wheel_scale is not a function`

```
<template>
   <div class="count-wheel">{{ scale }}</div>
   ...
   <div id="singapore-map"></div>
</template>

...
export default {
   data() {
      return {
         scale: 1
      }
   },
   mounted() {
      var sg = document.getElementById("singapore-map");
      sg.parentElement.addEventListener("wheel", function (e){
         this.wheel_scale(e, sg);
      });
   },
   methods: {
    wheel_scale: function (e, t) {
       e.wheelDelta < 0 ? this.scale-- : this.scale++;
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: It should work. I just created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/or8bjLfv/. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're assigning a scoped function to `sg` element's parent.

Inside that function, `this` is not the current Vue instance, but **that** function's `this` (which does not have a `wheel_scale` function).

To fix the problem, bind an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
   // ...
   sg.parentElement.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
     this.wheel_scale(e, sg);
   });
   // ...
```

---

That being said, I can see at least two side problems with your component:

1. You seem to have more than 1 root element, which is a problem in Vue2. You might want to wrap the `<template>` contents inside one single `<div>`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="count-wheel">{{ scale }}</div>
    ...
    <div id="singapore-map"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

2. You should not interact with DOM directly. Do it through `ref`s:

```html
<div ref="singaporeMap"></div>
```

```js
  // ...
  mounted() {
    const sg = this.$refs.singaporeMap;
    if (sg instanceof HTMLDivElement) {
      sg.parentElement.addEventLisnter('wheel', (e) => {
        this.wheel_scale(e, sg);
      })
    }    
  }
  // ...
```

**Notes**:

- avoid using `.parentElement` when binding events. It's safer to put a class on the parent element you want to target and use `.closest('.some-class')`. [Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- When binding to elements outside of your component, always cleanup (remove the binding) in [`beforeDestroy()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy).